# Not able to access other folder rather than node.js app

Tags: node.js, apache2, angular-universal

I have deployed an angular universal app on port 4000 and I have used a reverse proxy to make it live on port 80.

Application Path:/var/html/www/eduglobe/eduglobe/ (this path i access as domainname.com)

But I am not able to access  Below path:/var/html/www/test/index.html ( This I am not able to access at domainname.com/test/index.html)

php and node.js server working fine.

Code for site-enabled 000-default.conf

```
    ProxyRequests Off


 <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ServerName demo.eduglobe.in
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/eduglobe/eduglobe




<Location />
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:4000/
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled proxy_http?

The followings works for me!

Check that the **Location** directive points to the folder that hosts the app which is not the **DocumentRoot** (/) of the site enabled.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

<Location /demo>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
</Location>
```